# mongoose: save is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, sveltekit

Given a user model:

```js
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose'

export interface User {
  email: string
}

const userSchema = new Schema<User>(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
)

export const UserModel = model<User>('User', userSchema)
```

I'm trying to save it as so:

```js
// inside an async function
const newUser: HydratedDocument<User> = new UserModel({
  email: 'aaa@aaa.com',
})

console.log(newUser)

await newUser.save()
```

Which results in `newUser.save is not a function`. What am I missing? Also, here is the output of the `console.log(newUser)

[image: Also, here is the output of the `console.log(newUser)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid mistake: I was calling everything on the fronted. Solution is as easy as moving relevant db calls to the endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to also define a model, change your schema definition to this:

first create model from Schema :

```js
 var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

then create object out of User model

```js
 var user = new UserModel(req.body)
```

then call

```js
 user.save(function(){});
```

check documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save